# Indian National Trip to Nepal from Malaysia as tourist

Tags: indian-citizens, india, nepal

I'm an Indian National and presently in Malaysia and wants to travel to Nepal and from Nepal I intend to drive to India. Do I need to get an immigration chop at Kathmandu airport while arriving into Nepal from Malaysia or I can simply show my Driving License.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt with a driving license after you are going to Nepal via air, but you can show your Passport to get a stamp in Immigration. That's all. Simply land to Kathmandu, go to the Immigration agent, show your passport. They will stamp it for your entry.

Some times Aadhar Card will also work as it depends upon Immigration person as you only need to verify that you are Indian.

After that, you can take any means of transportation to get to India via road either Gorkhapur exit, Rakshwal exit or mid-western side of Nepal exit point to the driver and get in India.

Comment: Thanks.. so they give an arrival departure stamp at airport or chop a Nepalese visa on passport while entering the Country through Kathmandu Airport

Comment: @CAPTANANT: for you, they will put the stamp of entry only. No Nepalese visa will be there for you as it is free to pass for Indian in Nepal and vice versa.